# MultiPartFile is null when Content-Disposition does not contain filename attribute

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator, content-disposition

in my openapi generated client for spring I'm receive MultipartFile objects. This works fine in most cases.

But when someone is calling my endpoint with the Content-Disposition missing the filename attribute it does not work. As soon as the attribute is added but the value is empty it does work.

ERROR:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
```

OK:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=
```

Any ideas what I might need to adjust here? Or is it just not possible to do it like that?

I tried to change the api to upload files differently, but it is necessary to upload the file with additional meta data in one single request so I am dependent on multipart in this case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit your question to explain what you mean by *Any ideas what I might need to adjust here? Or is it just not possible to do it like that?* - why is the behavior you have described a problem for you? Can't the consumer just pass a valid filename?